# autocomplete tag of jsp

Tags: jsp, autocomplete

I have very minimal knowledge in JSP and i have come across a tag "autocomplete"
Can anyone let me know if the do not specify this tag what will be its default value ?
For example :-
i have the code as below :-

```
<tr>    
        <td><b>Password</b></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""/></td>               
</tr>
```

Here i am not specifying autocomplete so will the default value be false or will it be true.

Thanks in advance for you help .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli : I am sorry i don't think its a duplicate issue. please read my query i am asking for the default value if iu am not specifying autocomplete

Comment: Default value is true. But some browsers make it off for security purposes. Please read answer of question.

Comment: There is no `autocomplete` tag in JSP, there is [autocomplete](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) **attribute** in HTML. Default value is `on`.